# Как оставить пунктуацию после обработки текста?

Tags: java

Моя программа принимает текст и выводит его проверяя каждое слово на повторение первой буквы с последующим удалением(**rare -> rae**).Но в моем случае , мы разделяем текст `split`om по определенным знакам пунктуации и получается, что на выходе их нет.(**Rare, very rare. -> Rae very rae.**). Каким образом вывести так:
**Rae, very rae.**?

И есть ли предложения по оптимизации *кода*, его улучшению?

*Код*:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab3 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        /*StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer("Slavasik soset huiuihi");
        String result = Arrays.stream(text.toString().split(" "))
                .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1) + s.replaceAll(s.substring(0, 1), ""))
                .reduce((s, s2) -> s + " " + s2).get();
        System.out.println(result);*/
        char answer;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter the text:");
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim());
            System.out.println(deleteDuplicatesFromString(sb));
            System.out.println("Continue checking another text? (y/n)");
            answer = scanner.nextLine().trim().charAt(0);
        } while (answer != 'n');
    }

    public static StringBuffer deleteDuplicatesFromString(StringBuffer inputString){
        StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer(inputString);
        String[] words = inputString.toString().split("([\\.,!?:\\-])(\\s)|\\s|[\\.,!?:\\-]");
        temp.delete(0, temp.length());
        if(inputString.length() < 2 || inputString == null){
            return inputString;
        }
        else{
            for(String word : words){
                char distChar = word.charAt(0);
                temp.append(distChar);
                for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
                    if(distChar != word.charAt(i)){
                        temp.append(word.charAt(i));
                    }
                }
                temp.append(" ");
            }
            return temp;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переписанный метод deleteDuplicatesFromString:

```
 public static StringBuffer deleteDuplicatesFromString(StringBuffer inputString)
    {
        StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer(inputString);
        String[] words = inputString.toString().split(" ");
        temp.delete(0, temp.length());
        if(! (inputString.length() < 2 || inputString == null))
        {
            for(String word : words){
                char distChar = word.charAt(0);
                temp.append(distChar);
                for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
                    if(Character.toLowerCase(distChar) != 
                             Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i))){
                        temp.append(word.charAt(i));
                    }
                }

                temp.append(" ");
            }

        }
        return temp;
    }
```